# How to add new value to textbox in a do while loop

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on an assignment for school. The goal is to loop a window with the value of a textbox till I enter the value "0" in it.

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Do
    {

      // code

    }
    While(tbInput.Text != "0")
}
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to solve this. When I enter a value in the textbox and press the button, the window (sort of) freezes. This is because the code keeps looping with the same value that I put in the textbox. How can I make it available to add a new value in the textbox at the start of the Do-While loop?

Comment: What do you need to do when the value is `"0"` ?

Comment: @user3185569 I need to show a messagebox with the result. The result is being calculated in the code between my do while.

Comment: Do you mean untill the last digit in the text box is zero ?

Comment: I have found the answer but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `do .. while` loop here since you are checking that on button click. So you can just check for the textbox value and if doesn't match then return a messagebox saying doesn't match and retain focus to the textbox.

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     if(tbInput.Text != "0")
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Doesn't Match...");
        FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(parentElement, tbInput);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This sovled my problem.

Comment: @tranquilX, welcome, then consider accepting the answer by clicking the check button under voting button